# Print without scrolling down

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm printing in a full screen python3 terminal for my application, the terminal has room for 63 lines, lets scale it down, lets say the terminal has 10 lines and I print 13, it would look like this

```
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
line 11
line 12
line 13
```

and you would have to scroll up to see the line 1, line 2, & line 3
How do I print from the beginning of the line like so

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

where you have to scroll down to see the line 11, line 12, & line 13

Comment: _...full screen python3 terminal_, which one ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer For now I'm just using my MacOS terminal shell

Comment: Does your script just print these lines and quit? Pipe the output through `less`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: IMHO this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from [@Jhonny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp) :

> Does your script just print these lines and quit? Pipe the output through `less`

So if the name of your script is `script.py`, just do :

```
python script.py | less
```